# iOS & SpriteKit - low fps after restarting the game

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skscene

I have created a simple iPhone game where user is redirected to another view after loosing the game and can clik "Start again" to play it again.

When the game starts it runs smooth and it has around 60 fps, the problem starts when he looses the game and stars again.

**GameViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            /*
               ... some code ...
            */

            scene.gameOverFunc = gameOverScreen

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

func gameOverScreen(){

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.presentScene(nil)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gmov", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
func gameOver(){
        /*
           ... some code ...
        */

        if let gmovFunc = gameOverFunc {
            gmovFunc()
        } 

    }


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        gameOver()
    }
```

I have set a segue from the "game over" screen to GameViewController.
Performance of the game drops after each new game.
Do I have to destroy the instance of SKScene or something before leaving to "game over" screen ?

Comment: This could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052659/memory-increase-in-spritekit-even-though-removeallchildren-called

Answer (score 0):

The segue from GameOver to GameViewController will create another instance. of the ViewController and the Scene. Therefore your performance will drop.  You need to `unwind` the segue instead of creating a new instance of the ViewController with `performSegue`.

Comment: Here is a tutorial which explains this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2