# Memory Increase in SpriteKit even though removeAllChildren called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, memory, sprite-kit

I've been trying to fix a huge memory increase in SpriteKit for many weeks now but have found no solution. I have tried just about every method that I've come across online for managing memory in SK but am still having troubles. Here's my situation:

I first present the SKScene "HomeScreen" and from there I am changing Page scenes with a UIButton in my View Controller like so:

```
 func nextPage(sender: UIButton) {

    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1

    let switchPage = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(3.0)
    switchPage.pausesOutgoingScene = false

    switch pageNumber {
    case 1: self.skView.presentScene(Page01(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 2: self.skView.presentScene(Page02(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 3: self.skView.presentScene(Page03(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 4: self.skView.presentScene(Page04(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 5: self.skView.presentScene(Page05(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 6: self.skView.presentScene(Page06(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 7: self.skView.presentScene(Page07(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 8: self.skView.presentScene(Page08(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 9: self.skView.presentScene(Page09(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 10: self.skView.presentScene(Page10(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    case 11: self.skView.presentScene(Page11(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: switchPage)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And here is my memory graph from Xcode:

[image]

As you can see, my memory for HomeScreen (HS) starts at 38.1 and by the time I have cycled through all the scenes and come back to the Home Screen it ends at 112. I also loaded each page individually and recorded the memory to confirm the increase.

In each SKScene, I load various objects and then in willMoveFromView I am removing them as so:

```
    override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {

    //Remove the Scroller Components
    self.view?.removeGestureRecognizer(self.page01Drops.panGestureRecognizer)
    self.page01Drops = nil

    //Remove Environment
    self.randomObjectFromScene.texture = nil

    self.anotherRandomObject.removeFromParent

    self.removeAllActions()
    self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

Here's a little more info:
- Deinit is not being called after a scene changes.

- I have no leaks when testing the app with Instruments.
- All SKTextures are loaded first as UIImages using stringByAppendingPathComponent.
- All willMoveFromView methods contain removeAllActions and removeAllChildren.

Does anyone know why my memory is increasing?

**Update** A little more sample code

Here is how I load my skView in viewDidLoad:

```
    skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    skView.presentScene(homeScreen(size: skView.bounds.size))
```

And here is a bit from my Page01 SKScene:

```
class Page01: SKScene {
    //Preload Textures
    let aaronHead01Texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("P01_head01.png"))!)
    let aaronHead02Texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("P01_head02.png"))!)
    //more textures for body parts of character that will be changed

    var aaronHead: SKSpriteNode!
    //More SKSpriteNodes for other body parts

    override init(size: CGSize){
        super.init(size: size)

        self.aaronHead = SKSpriteNode(texture: self.aaronHead01Texture)
        self.aaronHead.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.1)
        self.aaronHead.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 284)
        self.aaronHead.zPosition = 1.0
        self.aaronBody.addChild(aaronHead)

    }
```

Comment: As appzYourLife pointed already, it might be that you have a strong reference cycle. Search about terms like unowned self, weak self etc.. Also take a peek at the docs (as best reference) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: If you want you can post the properties of some of your scenes as well as the properties of your view controller and I can take a look to see if I can find any obvious retain cycles. The fact that you said deinit is not getting called is proof that you definitely have a retain cycle somewhere in your code. You may also want to make a sample project with deinit working and slowly add your code in until deinit stops working. This is more of a trial and error approach but it will defiant to help you locate the issue.

Comment: Thanks Epic Byte, I just added some code. In each of my SKScenes, I create about 12 or so SKSpriteNodes for each of my characters' body parts that are parented together.

Comment: I have found that calling a block that runs self.aaronHead.texture = self.aaronHead02Texture gets retained.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html  in particular read the section Strong Reference Cycles for Closures which I believe may be causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks to this I figured out my main problem. If there is an active `SKAction.runBlock` when you call presentScene, then that closure is retained. So instead of using `let changeHead = SKAction.runBlock(self.aaronHead01)` I now use `let changeHead = SKAction.runBlock({[unused self] in self.aaronHead01()})`

Comment: @jwade502 You mean [unowned self] right? ;)

Comment: Oops! :) `let changeHead = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.aaronHead01()})` Also note that I am not simply using `SKAction.setTexture` because it is not available in iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found the problem:

> Deinit is not being called after a scene changes.

If when a `scene` does change the `deinit` of the old scene is not called then that's the problem. It means that the old scene is still in memory.

This is probably happening because you have a **strong retain cycle**. This means that a child (or a child of a child...) of your scene has a **strong reference** to the scene itself.

You must find that reference and declare it with the `weak` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the tip appzYourLife. Does this mean that things like SKNodes, SKSpriteNodes, or SKLabelNodes need to be set to weak?

Comment: @jwade502: Actually when you add an `SKNode` (or `SKSpriteNode` or `SKLabelNode`) to you scene (or to another node) you should just write         `self.addChild(anotherNode)`. SpriteKit will take care of the references. Are you creating properties to your nodes to reference other node?

Comment: Only for textures. I make SKTexture properties at the top of my init method, and then use those properties when I need to set a texture on an SKSpriteNode.

Comment: I still believe you have strong retain cycles. I suggest you to add this `deinit { debugPrint("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)).deinit") }` to every custom node you defined. Then run your game. When you change scene **every node** in your scene should be deinitializated. Just look for your instances that are not deallocated and find out which one is not. This means you have strong references to that nodes that should be declared weak.

Comment: I used this deinit method in a custom SKNode subclass I have called SpriteKitButton and it works, but that is the only outside class I am using. If I set my SKTexture properties to weak var then they glitch on and off while trying to be displayed on my iPad.

Comment: I suggest you to use `Instruments`. It will tell you exactly which objects are using memory.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I'll get started researching and testing.